# pass boolean intent between two activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have toggle bottun to display the service status  in the actionbar in the `MainActivity` and `Map` activity. After clicking a button, the user is being redirected to the map activity.  The boolean `serviceStauts` variable is to dectect the status of the service in both activity. I am facing problem to pass the boolean as intent to the map activity since the value is ture at the start  in the MainActivity and I am getting `false` in the map activity for `serviceStauts` when I click the button of the checklist (I am not touching the icon in the actionbar)!?

Can guide me why I am getting false in the map activity?

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
boolean serviceStauts = true;
 ....
    private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {
                        Intent serviceStatusIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Map.class);
                        serviceStatusIntent.putExtra("booleanServicfeStatus", serviceStauts);
                        startActivity(serviceStatusIntent);
     }
 .... 


@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_toggle:

            if (serviceStauts) {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
                item.setTitle("OFF");
                serviceStauts = false;
                mService.stopTrackingService();
                System.out.println("ABC Map onOptionsitemSelected OFF");            

            } else {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
                item.setTitle("ON");
                serviceStauts = true;
                Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
                startService(i);
                System.out.println("ABC Map onOptionsitemSelected ON");

            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

    }
```

**Map activity:**

```
public class Map extends ActionBarActivity {
boolean serviceStauts;

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);      
        serviceStauts = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("booleanServicfeStatus");
  }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        System.out.println("ABC MAP onPrepareOptionsMenu was invoked.");
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle);
        if(serviceStauts){
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
        }else{
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'I am getting false in the map activity for serviceStauts'. Where are you getting that?

Comment: This code is really all over the place, and not one answer will suffice. When you pass a bundle via intent, you are passing the *value*, not the reference, so changing your incorrectly-named `serviceStauts` variable in MainActivity won't change the value of the equally-incorrectly-named variable in MapActivity.

Comment: @greenapps: the `boolean serviceStauts = true;` is intialized in the MainActivity when I click the button of the checklist in the MainActivity I am receiving `false` in the `onNewIntent()` in the `Map` activity.

Comment: onNewIntent will not even be triggered. Place a Toast in it or a Log.

Comment: @greenapps: Also I am using the onNewIntent() in my map activity to receive another intent from the alarmmanger and the Intentservice which are triggered when the user clicks the  button in the MainActivity.  I thought I can receive the `bolean` value there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 'onNewIntent`for the first time an`Activity`is called, which means the`Extra`s are absent. Then you use`getBoolean`which defaults to`false` if the key doesn't exist.

You should not implement `onNewIntent` except under specific circumstances. And just use `getIntent` to get your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `Map`

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     serviceStauts = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("booleanServicfeStatus");
 }
```

You can remove your `onNewIntent` method, it is used for some other cases.